# Release IP address and shut down computers

Tags: powershell

I want to move 100 or so pcs from one site to another one. So, I need to release their IP addresses and then shut down them. I created below scripts by PS, however, they don't work well. Can someone modify them? Thanks.

```
$ethernet = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -cn (.\work\computers.txt) | Where { $_.IpEnabled -eq $true -and $_.DhcpEnabled -eq $true}   

foreach ($lan in $ethernet) { 
    Write-Host "$lan Flushing IP addresses" 
    $lan.ReleaseDHCPLease() | out-Null
    stop-computer -cn (.\work\computers.txt) -force  
}
```

Comment: "however, they don't work well" - please elaborate on this. Do you get any errors? What behavior do you expect and what behavior do you see?

Comment: Hello Tony, Always get error message: Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) I think it maybe the firewall blocks running the scripts, is it right? Do you have any experience to avoid it?

Comment: Hello Mathias, any idea for my question will be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: `-cn (.\work\computers.txt)` - will not work at all. It should be `-cn (Get-Content .\work\computers.txt)` at least. `stop-computer -cn (.\work\computers.txt)` - what do you expect from this line of code? It will (if added `Get-Content` before txt file) repeatedly shutdown _all_ listed in file computers every round of a cycle like "shutdown all; shutdown all; shutdown all; etc".

Comment: Change the scripts to simple ones. -cn s48801010 instead of -cn (get-content .\work\computers.txt). Still get the same error message. Any another idea? Thanks.